# AnythingSlider Images & Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, anythingslider

I noticed that there’s a AnythingSlider Video Extension. Is it possible to have combination of images & video in the same slider using this ext?

The demo (http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/video.html#&panel1-1) just uses videos & so far have not seen an example using mixed content in same slider.

Answer (score 1):

I have the anything slider that was 324px tall.  I changed the type to html.  I used the:
 Shortcode >Media to insert my Vimeo vid.  Then I created an image that was 324px tall.  Used html to insert it at the top of the page:

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.WEBSITE.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/rocks-bannerbar.png" />
```

In next section, I was using the 2 column layout as you can see so ignore that.  Under the Text tab (not visual tab) Had to instruct the video this way with the margin-top code:

```
[one_half_last]
<p style="padding-left: 30px; margin-top: -320px;">[video type="vimeo" clip_id="12345678" width="275" height="212"][/one_half_last]</p>
```

This pulled the video up ontop of the image.  Now I have a banner image under the video inside my slider object!

Comment: Hello, Joshua.  You need to add some mark-up formatting so that your code shows up as code (instead of StackOverflow trying to interpret it): four spaces in front of each line of code does it.

Answer (score 0):

Each panel of AnythingSlider is ultimately just a `li` with content in it, so you can really put any content you like inside that `li`, including text, images, a video etc. Just make sure those elements fit within the width/height of the `li`.

Comment: I think the problem is that just adding video to an LI doesn't stop the slider once video is started (jQuery doesn't detect the click since it's embed).  So what happens is: (1) user clicks video (2) it starts to play (3) slider goes to next slide replacing video but audio still playing in background.  

The video ext addresses that issue, but have not seen example using both images & video.